# Can I reverse a passive high pass filter?

Tags: filter

Can the passive high pass filter be used in reverse? (exchange TX and ANT)

I have a passive  HPF, but I don't know if it is possible to reverse the port using.If I do this, will it cause the HPF to burn out, under 100w power.

It will become a low pass filter?

Comment: In general, no, that's not possible. There are symmetrical filter architectures that you could use forward as backwards. "Under 100W power" is a bit vague. 100 W is really a lot! "I have a car that goes less than 270 km/h, can I break it by driving backwards" is about as specific. So, please tell us all you know about your filter and your application. Which frequencies? Which type of high-pass filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to reverse the components, not the ports:

[image]

Of course it depends on the circuit design.